# How to Plot a two line graph out of three tabular columns in R

Tags: r, rstudio

[image: looking for the line graph with 2 lines one projected shadowed, and a dark line produced.][image: Not what I want]  This definitely not what I wanted. I'm learning to plot, but I want my x value to be dates and my y value to be line graphs telling the story of projected vs performed values. So far here is what I have which is not what I want.

```
ggplot(testPlot, aes(x = Date, y = Performed)) +
  geom_point()
```

The columns that I have are:
[image: Tabular Data]

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example? You can use `dput()`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you should provide a reproducible example to allow people to better help you. But just guessing at what you are doing:

Your data seems to be `testPlot` and the `Date` field doesn't seem to have a year. You are also trying to create a line graph using a character or factor as the x-axis, which won't work.

This is an example using the `mpg` dataset that you can look at that will work.

```
ggplot(mpg2, aes(model, hwy, col = class)) +
  geom_line()
```

You might want to change your months to proper months, perhaps use the `lubridate` package.